# What is WSM Buffer in Data Power

Tags: ibm-datapower

What is WSM Buffer in IBM DataPower's context?
As per my understanding, WSM Buffer is used to monitor incoming requests in DataPower. The statistics for all incoming requests such as 'completed records', 'pending records' etc are captured in 'WSM Agent Status' in DataPower.

Can you please provide a detailed description of WSM Buffer and how does it help in logging and monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

A WSM buffer is relatively easy to configure setting in datapower XI52. You need to enable it like following:

1. Use the DataPower Web Interface
2. Navigate to Object > Device Management
3. Enable data retention in the WSM buffer
       Select XML Management Interface
       Check the WS-Management Endpoint checkbox
       Click Apply
4. Choose to retain data when data collection is stopped
5. Select Web Services Management Agent
   Select Buffering Mode = Buffer
   Click Apply

Then you need to use products like ITCAM for SOA which have capability to read WSM buffer and make sense out of it. You need to configure ITCAM for SOA for it. Once done you can test your WSM buffer configuration like below:

Send four requests to your DataPower device
Check the WSM buffer
    1.Choose Status > Web Service > WSM Agent Status
    2. Status is 4 (for example) records seen, 4 (for example) complete records
Parameters have following meaning
    a.) Records seen: total lost + complete
    b.) Records lost: discarded when the buffer was full
    c.) Complete records: ready for data collection
    d.) Pending records: requests awaiting a server response

See if it helps you !